# Twitter PHP API - Places

Tags: php, twitter, twitter-oauth

I have created a simple twitter app to show trends in a location. It seems to work but compared to http://trendsmap.com/local/gb/liverpool it shows different results.

my code:

```
<?php
require_once('TwitterAPIExchange.php');

/** Set access tokens here - see: https://dev.twitter.com/apps/ **/
$settings = array(
    'oauth_access_token' => "1",
    'oauth_access_token_secret' => "1",
    'consumer_key' => "1",
    'consumer_secret' => "1"
);

$url = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/trends/place.json";

$requestMethod = "GET";

$getfield = '?id=26734';

$twitter = new TwitterAPIExchange($settings);
echo $twitter->setGetfield($getfield)
             ->buildOauth($url, $requestMethod)
             ->performRequest();
?>
```

It returns data but not as expected, any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Are you getting data from the same location? Liverpool, England?

Comment: yes the trend is supposed to be from liverpool, uk

Comment: What in the code states that?

Comment: id=26734 This ID is the id for Liverpool using the method Twitter suggests